# Hyperlinks do not work with cleveref (beamer)

Tags: beamer, hyperref, cleveref

In the MWE below, you will see that `\cref` is not working with `hyperref`. Also, even with the conventional `\ref` command, `hyperref` leads to the wrong equation

This is the output

[image]

This is where `\ref` takes us (right under Equation 1, instead of Equation 1 itself)

[image]

One solution is mentioned in [cleveref hyperlink not working in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266080/cleveref-hyperlink-not-working-in-beamer) redefines `\cref` as follows

```
\let\chyperref\cref % Save the orginal command under a new name
\renewcommand{\cref}[1]{{\hyperlink{#1}{\chyperref{#1}}}} % Redefine the \cref command and explictely add the hyperlink.
```

The solution above works only to reference only one equation. If multiple equations are referenced, hyperlink will always take us to the beginning of the document. This means that `\cref` with this solution is pretty much the same as `\ref`

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\useoutertheme[]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=1cm, sidebar width right=1cm}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.5mm, text margin right=0.5mm}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor=SlateBlue2, citebordercolor=SlateBlue2, 
linkbordercolor=DodgerBlue3, linkcolor=DodgerBlue3, urlcolor=Blue1, colorlinks=true}

\usepackage{cleveref}

    % Single equations (non-breakable)
    \crefformat{equation}{\mbox{Eq. #2(#1)#3}}
    \crefrangeformat{equation}{\mbox{Eqs. #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}}
    \crefmultiformat{equation}{\mbox{Eqs. #2(#1)#3}}{ and #2(#1)#3}{, #2(#1)#3}{ and #2(#1)#3}
    \crefrangemultiformat{equation}{\mbox{Eqs. #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}}{ and #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}{, #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}{ and #3(#1)#4 to #5(#2)#6}

\let\chyperref\cref % Save the orginal command under a new name
\renewcommand{\cref}[1]{{\color{blue}\hyperlink{#1}{\chyperref{#1}}}} % Redefine the \cref command and explictely add the hyperlink. 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title Here}

    \begin{block}

        \begin{align}
            A  &= B
            \label{eq1}
            \\
             &= C
             \label{eq2}
             \\
             &= D
             \label{eq3}
        \end{align}

    \end{block}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Title Here}

    \begin{block}

        \begin{align}
            A  &= B
            \label{eq4}
            \\
             &= C
             \label{eq5}
             \\
             &= D
             \label{eq6}
        \end{align}

    \end{block}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Title Here}

\begin{block}

    \begin{align}
    A  &= B
    \label{eq7}
    \\
    &= C
    \label{eq8}
    \\
    &= D
    \label{eq9}
    \end{align}

\end{block}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    contents in between
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}

    \cref{eq1} 

    \cref{eq1,,eq2}

    \cref{eq1,eq2,eq3} 

    \cref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq7,eq8,eq9} 

    \cref{eq1,,eq2,,eq3,eq7,eq8,eq9} 

    \cref{eq6,eq7,eq9} 


    Eq. \ref{eq1} 
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the output you get to your question? If I compile  your code, I get the following in slide 3: eqs. (1) and (2)
Eq. 1  Maybe interesting: [cleveref hyperlink not working in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/266080/134144)

Answer (score 3):

No, hyperrefs with cleverref and beamer don't work.  You only need to compile a small beamer document with cleverref and then look in the log:

```
Package cleveref Warning: hyperref package loaded with implicit=false option - 
disabling cleveref's hyperref support. This situation is not supported by cleveref, 
and there's no guarantee anything will work. You're on your own! on input 
line 2370.
```

Comment: How is this helpful? I can see this error message myself, that's the reason I came here in the first place.

Comment: @NikitaSkybytskyi Not everyone looks in the log and see such message. And even less accept what is written there: "This is not supported" and "You're on your own!".