# Cleveref and tcolorbox for theorems that share a counter

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox, counters, cleveref, amsthm

I'd like to have different theorem environments share the same counter using tcolorbox in beamer. However `cleveref` doesn't seem to pick up their names correctly. Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{lemma}{lemma}{lemmas}
\crefname{theorem}{theorem}{theorems}

\renewtcolorbox[use counter=theorem]{theorem}[1][]{
    title={\thetheorem. Theorem.},
    before upper={\tcbtitle\;\itshape},
    #1
    }

\renewtcolorbox[use counter=theorem]{lemma}[1][]{
    title={\thetheorem. Lemma.},
    before upper={\tcbtitle\;\itshape},
    #1
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Blah}
    \begin{theorem}[label=bar]
        Blah blah.
    \end{theorem}
    \cref{bar}

    \begin{lemma}[label=foo]{}{}
        Blah blah.
    \end{lemma}
    \cref{foo}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:
[image: output]

I would like "lemma 2" instead of "theorem 2". I tried adding `label type = lemma` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615322/cleveref-with-a-same-counter-used-in-multiple-environments-of-newtcbtheorem), but without any success.

Comment: Since `beamer` loads `hyperref` with package option `implicit=false`, `cleveref` doesn't work with `beamer` (as can be seen from the `Package cleveref warning` in log) and there seems to be no easy workaround. Similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481055.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ As far as I know, the issue you mentioned affects the `hyperref`'s anchors (the links will all point to DocStart). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266109/105447 for a (partial) work-around. However, are your sure it affects the reference counter/type too?

Comment: I think what's happening is that `beamer` can't handle the optional argument to `\label` which `cleveref` adds and `tcolorbox` uses to implement `label type`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beamer` is quite peculiar in it's treatment of cross-referencing but, if you are willing to use `zref-clever`, and do some setup, you may get away with the following:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

% Create 'zlabel' and 'zlabel type' options for tcolorbox.
\tcbset{%
  zlabel/.style={phantom={\zlabel{#1}}},%
  zlabel type/.code={\zcsetup{reftype={#1}}},%
}

\usepackage{zref-clever}

% From "Work-around 2: beamer" in zref-clever's User manual
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\zlabel}{ D<>{1} m }{%
  \ifx\label\ltx@gobble
  \else
    \zref@wrapper@babel{\zref@label<#1>}{#2}%
  \fi
}
\NewCommandCopy\beamer@old@zref@label\zref@label
\RenewDocumentCommand{\zref@label}{ D<>{1} m }{%
  \alt<#1>{%
    \zref@ifpropundefined{anchor}{}{\zref@setcurrent{anchor}{#2}}%
    \beamer@old@zref@label{#2}%
    \beamer@nameslide{#2}%
  }{%
    \beamer@dummynameslide%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\renewtcolorbox[use counter=theorem]{theorem}[1][]{
    title={\thetheorem. Theorem.},
    before upper={\tcbtitle\;\itshape},
    #1
    }

\renewtcolorbox[use counter=theorem]{lemma}[1][]{
    title={\thetheorem. Lemma.},
    zlabel type={lemma},
    before upper={\tcbtitle\;\itshape},
    #1
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \zcref{bar,foo}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Blah}
  \begin{theorem}[zlabel=bar]
    Blah blah.
  \end{theorem}
  \zcref{bar}

  \begin{lemma}[zlabel=foo]
    Blah blah.
  \end{lemma}
  \zcref{foo}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked great – thanks!