# Easily switch figure size from beamer to article (and vice versa)

Tags: beamer, macros, graphics, includegraphics, beamerarticle

**My question**

How can I improve this `\newcommand` that enables me to have

1. a centered figure with captions in mode `article`
2. a centered graph with a title in `beamer`
3. The title in `beamer` is the caption in `article`

[image]
[image]

```
%------------    %0= Article 1= beamer    --------------
\def\model{1} 
%----------------load the documentclass ----------------
\if 0\model
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[envcountsect]{beamerarticle}
\else
  \documentclass{beamer}
\fi
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\hackGraph}[3]{
  \if 0\model
    \begin{figure}[htp]
      \centering
      #1
      \caption{#3}
    \end{figure}
  \else
    \begin{frame}{#3}
      \centering
      #2
    \end{frame}
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\hackGraph
  {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}}
  {\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image}}
  {Figure with caption or frame with title} 

\end{document}
```

**context**

I use `beamer` and `beameraticle` to generate either Notes or slides.
Following the "no figure in beamer" principle, I created `\hackGraph` for all my `includegraphics` and `\input{TikZ.tex}`

For instance

```
\hackGraph
  {\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{\input{TikZ.tex}}}
  {\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{\input{TikZ.tex}}}
  {TikZ figure with caption or frame with title}
```

works as well to wrap/resize my figures in `TikZ`.

But I see while using it that I don't do things the right way.

The code seems too repetitive. How could it be improved ?

Comment: Your `\hackGraph` already fits your requirement, and you are asking for possible improvements?

Comment: Does the width constraint (`0.5\textwidth` for `beamerarticle` and `0.8\textwidth` for `beamer`) fixed for every image and tikz graph, or variable from image to image?

Comment: Your `\model` switch is very close to `beamer`'s `\mode` internal macro. Have a look at the `beameruseguide` section 21.3. Also, while it was formerly advised to not use `figure` environments in `beamer`, they can actually be used transparently (the only difference is that they do not float) so there is no reason for you to avoid this environment in your presentation.

Comment: Side-notes : why do you use the frame title as a caption ? Otherwise, either with articles or presentations, I rarely compile `tikzpictures` inside my documents.  At the end of the day it takes much more time, especially if you have complex graphs like `pgfplots` axes. I prefer to include them with a good old `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ I am indeed looking for potential improvements. So far, I input  manually the percentage of `textwidth/textwidth` for each figure. But i imagine there is a smarter way to adapt automatically the size (`aspect ratio` ?).

Comment: @BambOo I agree, no figure in `beamer` :) that was actually the original reason for these `\hackGraph` (I have also `\hackTable` that wraps tabular the same way). historically, I planned to write only `beamer` presentations. But over time, students required more an more another display of the course content. I must confess I was not super good at understanding the `mode` system and made do with my `model` switch, but i probably reach a limit now.

Comment: @BambOo Regarding your side-note, I `externalize` my tikzfigure to avoid re-compilation when not needed. I use the caption as frametitle. It forces me to be efficient in my caption description to fit in 1 line on my frametitle.

Comment: `\mode` is not that difficult to use, but some content in `beamer` `presentation` mode cannot be handled in `article` mode, so there is some internal limit anyway to this conversion. I believe it will give you less trouble to discard your own switch and focus on the content, let `beamer` take care of the rest. Finally, I think if I were in the same situation, I would just make a separate content, regardless of the `beamer` just for flexibility reasons. To me presentations must really have only the necessary information, but I never had to teach a course so ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108322/discussion-between-julien-elie-taieb-and-bamboo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late, but I only found your question one month ago in search for something similar. Since then, I have worked out what I was looking for and I believe it is in line with what you need/requested.

It was important to me that I would NOT define my own switch, but instead use the `mode<presentation>{}` or `mode<article>{}` commands (since they are available already). But because those commands are provided by beamer, they do not work in article mode until you have loaded `\usepackage{beamerarticle}`. In other words, you cannot use `mode<article>{\usepackage{beamerarticle}}`. However, you can use:

```
\@ifclassloaded{article}{\usepackage{beamerarticle}}
```

Effectively, this can become a conditional statement which ensures that you load `beamerarticle`, only when you typeset your `documentclass` as article.

While I am aware that the figure environment should not be used in beamer, I actually need it in article mode and (thanks to the `[H]` option provided by the `float` package) it works really well for me - in both modes. In addition (similar to what you were looking for), it was important to me to have one single .tex file that produces both, a presentation and a full-blown article (with proper figure environment).

To use the figure caption in other places (like the frame title), you can use the `cleveref` package (according to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266080/cleveref-hyperlink-not-working-in-beamer/266109#266109)).

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
% Create more complete clever ref to use
% figure label for auto generation frame title 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\mode<presentation>{
\let\Chyperref\Cref % Save original command under a new name
\renewcommand{\Cref}[1]{\hyperlink{#1}{\Chyperref{#1}}} % Redefine \cref command and explicitly add the hyperlink. 
\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\Cref{#1}:~\nameref{#1}}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\mode<article>{
\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\Cref*{#1}: \nameref*{#1}}}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Because the hyperlink is slightly different in beamer mode than it is in article mode, it is defined seperately (That way, you can also make adjustments for each individual output version, depending on your needs).

Now you can use the `captionsetup` command from the `caption` package to make the standard figure caption disappear.

```
\captionsetup[figure]{
labelformat=empty,
textformat=empty,
}
```

If need to be, you can set this per mode (for example use `\mode<presentation>{\captionsetup[figure]{...}}` if you only want to adjust the caption in beamer). Likewise, you could also change this setting anywhere throughout the document.

With those settings in place, you can now use a frame like this:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\fullref{fig: my label}}

\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{My Caption}
\label{fig: my label}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}
```

And finally, here is a full minimal working example, for your review. Note that the switch comes in form of `%` in lines 1 and 2.

### Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}  % Comment out for article
%\documentclass{article}    % Uncomment line for article

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin Load Packages %%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Packages needed in article mode 
\makeatletter
\@ifclassloaded{article}{
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Automatically loaded in Beamer, but not in Article mode
\usepackage{hyperref}   % Automatically loaded in Beamer, but not in Article mode
}
\makeatother

% Packages needed in both modes
\usepackage{float}      % Allows use of figure environment  in Beamer (using [H]) 
\usepackage{caption}    % Needed to adjust caption
\usepackage{cleveref}   % Needed to adjust cross referencing 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% End Load Packages %%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Begin Custom Commands %%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
% Create more complete clever ref to use
% figure label for auto generation frame title 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\mode<presentation>{
% Idea stolen from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266080/cleveref-hyperlink-not-working-in-beamer/266109#266109
\let\Chyperref\Cref % Save original command under a new name
\renewcommand{\Cref}[1]{\hyperlink{#1}{\Chyperref{#1}}} % Redefine \cref command and explicitly add the hyperlink. 
\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\Cref{#1}:~\nameref{#1}}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\mode<article>{
\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\Cref*{#1}: \nameref*{#1}}}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Make the standard caption disappear
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Can be encased in \mode<presentation>{} 
% to use standard caption in article mode
%
%\mode<presentation>{
\captionsetup[figure]{
labelformat=empty,
textformat=empty,
}
%}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% End Custom Commands %%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
% Standard fix for 2018 LaTeX release
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\makeatletter
\let\@@magyar@captionfix\relax
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\fullref{fig: my label 1}}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=6cm]{example-image}
\caption{My First Figure Caption}
\label{fig: my label 1}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\mode<article>{
In my workflow, I need the figure caption in the frame title (in beamer) 
and above the image (in article). However, this can be easily adjusted 
through the ``mode switch'' 
}


\mode<article>{
\captionsetup[figure]{
labelformat=simple,
textformat=simple,
}}


\begin{frame}
\mode<presentation>{\frametitle{ \fullref{fig: my label 2}}}
\mode<article>{\frametitle{My Second Frame}}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=6cm]{example-image}
\caption{My Second Figure Caption}
\label{fig: my label 2}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This works really well for me, but I would love to hear your and the community feedback, as I am always interested in improvements or simpler methods. This is the most minimalistic version that I could come up with, but if there is a better method, I would love to know and use that.

### Example of Beamer Output:

[image: Beamer Mode]

### Example of Article Output:

[image: Article Mode]