# Test if \iffoo is defined before using it

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles, conditionals, overlays

When using `tikz` in a non-trivial document, the library  `external` is necessary to make PDF build time acceptable (unless one makes a separate TikZ PDF for each figure).

Unfortunately, this library has a number of bugs, such as not working with Beamer overlays. There are fixes, such as
[this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119428/24004):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{external}
  \tikzexternalize
\makeatletter
\ifdefined\ifbeamer@anotherslide  
\tikzset{
  beamer externalising/.style={%
    execute at end picture={%
      \tikzifexternalizing{%
        \ifbeamer@anotherslide
          \pgfexternalstorecommand{\string\global\string\beamer@anotherslidetrue}%
        \fi
      }{}%
    }%
  }, external/optimize=false, every picture/.style={beamer externalising}
}
\fi
\makeatother
 
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node {A\qquad\ };
      \pause
      \node {B};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The TikZ picture has an overlay, due to the `\pause` command, and the output is properly generated because of the `\tikzset{...}` fix.

I would like to put this command in a separate `.sty` file, together with other general purpose hacks.
Of course, if I loaded the style file from a non-Beamer document, `\ifbeamer@anotherslide` would be undefined.
So I need to make the `\tikzset{...}` command conditional to the Beamer class loading and/or `\ifbeamer@anotherslide`  being defined. I tried several things along these lines:

```
%%% hack.sty
\ifdefined\ifbeamer@anotherslide  
  \tikzset{
    beamer externalising/.style={%
      execute at end picture={%
        \tikzifexternalizing{%
          \ifbeamer@anotherslide
            \pgfexternalstorecommand{\string\global\string\beamer@anotherslidetrue}%
          \fi
        }{}%
      }}, external/optimize=false, every picture/.style={beamer externalising}
  }
\fi
```

However, constructs like:

```
\ifdefined\iffoo
 \iffoo
   % do stuff
 \fi
\fi
```

are illegal.

How can I have the `\tikzset` command above to be run only when it is necessary, that is, when there is a Beamer document using overlays, and not when other types of documents are used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a general use case, you can use `\@ifclassloaded{beamer}{<code for beamer>}{<code for other classes>}` to test for the current class.

In case your non-beamer documents happen to use the `beamerarticle` package, you could also test with modes, e.g. `\mode<beamer>{code for beamer class}` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/657316/36296 for an example).

---

Unrelated to the question, but I wouldn't use `\pause` inside a tikzpicture, this can have all kinds of "funny" side effects, like making footlines disappear. Instead either use the overlay awareness of tikz nodes or have a look at the `overlay-beamer-styles` tikz library.

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}


\documentclass{beamer}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{external}
  \tikzexternalize
\makeatletter
\@ifclassloaded{beamer}{
\ifdefined\ifbeamer@anotherslide  
\tikzset{
  beamer externalising/.style={%
    execute at end picture={%
      \tikzifexternalizing{%
        \ifbeamer@anotherslide
          \pgfexternalstorecommand{\string\global\string\beamer@anotherslidetrue}%
        \fi
      }{}%
    }%
  }, external/optimize=false, every picture/.style={beamer externalising}
}
\fi
}{}
\makeatother
 
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node<+-> {A\qquad\ };
      \node<+-> {B};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way out for your `\iffoo` problem: the idea is to *never* use `\iffoo`, so TeX will never “see” conditionals.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\BooleanExistsTF}{mmm}
 {
  \cs_if_exist:cTF { if#1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\BooleanExistsT}{mm}
 {
  \cs_if_exist:cT { if#1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\BooleanTF}{mmm}
 {
  \legacy_if:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\BooleanExistsTF{foo}{%
  \BooleanTF{foo}{YES}{NO}%
}{DOESN'T EXIST}

\newif\iffoo

\BooleanExistsT{foo}{%
  \BooleanTF{foo}{YES}{NO}%
}

\footrue

\BooleanExistsT{foo}{%
  \BooleanTF{foo}{YES}{NO}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to define also `\BooleanExistsF`, `\BooleanT` or `\BooleanF`.