# How to customise beamer equation cross-references?

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

I am currently trying to modify `beamer` equation references without success. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

Check \ref{eq} below.
\begin{gather}\label{eq}
    f(x)=y
\end{gather}
I want to get ``eq. 1'' rather than just ``1'' in my reference above. I need the entire ``eq. 1'' expression to be clickable. I have tried a few things to no avail. Any help?

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This MWE generates the following output:

[image]

I need what the MWE itself states: namely, **a clickable “eq. 1” rather than a clickable “1”**. In other document classes, I would normally achieve this by using `cleveref`, but apparently `cleveref` and `beamer` are not good friends.

Any help?

Comment: try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266109/36296

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I would be more concerned about the spacing between the f and the (.

Comment: @mickep Thank you for your comment. While the MWE output is ugly, the real output of my beamer presentation is *completely* different from the one shown here. So, nothing to worry there, really.

Comment: @Hector This warning is to be expected. Did you try the proposed workaround? The links seem to work just fine.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes, the linked answer kind of works, but I won’t be using it because the references are broken. In other words, clicking on them takes me all the way up to the beginning of my beamer presentation (rather than to the correct equation). All in all, I have decided that getting to fine-tune the references as I desire is too much work to be worth it. So I’m just giving up.

Comment: @Hector https://pastebin.com/GjszkGfQ works fine for me and jumps to the correct slide

Comment: You are completely right: applying the linked solution to my MWE works just fine. However, I must be doing something in my real Beamer document that breaks this expected behaviour. Since I am getting no errors nor warnings of any kind in my real Beamer, I do not know what it is that I am breaking down. And since my Beamer presentation is rather large, I can’t figure out by myself what’s going on. So, I just gave up.

Comment: [CONTINUED] Another problem is having two equations in the same reference, like `\cref{eq1,eq2}`. That scenario also fails, as the proposed solution hyperlinks the conjunction between the two equations, which is something it should not be doing. So, all in all, too much of a hassle…

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz What is it that `beamer` does that breaks the linking for `cleveref`? Do you happen to know if it affects `zref` too? (If not, I might offer a `zref-clever` answer...).

Comment: @gusbrs Beamer loads the hyperref package with `implicit=false`, which is not supported by cleveref https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/865a19d4ec64f4c8e4935c19e162b8f4fd5aa190/base/beamerbasenavigation.sty#L863-L865

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I've seen what this means in `hyperref`, and it's pretty drastic, much more than just `cleveref`. I've tested it here, and it defeats `zref` too, because it apparently breaks `hyperref` anchoring scheme (every anchor goes to `Doc-Start`). I'll take a look at this later, and see, if I can find some similar workaround. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @gusbrs You're welcome! (there is also a bug report about this https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/750 )

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Would you like me to include a `zref` example there too? (Or open a separate report?)

Comment: @gusbrs Please feel to add one if you have it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you all for your comments: I learned something today! I just logged in to this site to vote to close this question, as I thought it would get no useful answers any time soon; but apparently it may help improve some packages / documentclasses, so I no longer see the need to close it. Please, anyone with more experience with the site correct me if wrong.

Comment: @Hector Perhaps you might be interested in this `zref-clever` based work-around: https://github.com/gusbrs/zref-clever/blob/680dbe3c82f1bf329dfa891c54ad6b04a56474e5/zref-clever.tex#L2326-L2417

Comment: @gusbrs Thank you very much for this link! It looks really promising. I’m a bit busy now, but I will check it later and will report back whether it works or not.